# Facebook Graph API publish picture with Javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Facebook Javascript SDK in my react app and I want to make a post with multiple photos. I know that that means I have to first post the pictures unpublished and then use the returned ids to make the post.

However, I'm having trouble finding good documentation and running into issues figuring out how to allow a user select and post a local picture (not from a url). The code is a bit difficult to put all here, but here are the steps I'm taking and the errors I'm getting:

1. Get file the user selected using a file input.
2. Encode the picture as a blob and put that and the access token into FormData to use in the api request.

   ```
   var reader = new FileReader();

   reader.onload = function(e) {
       var arrayBuffer = e.target.result;

       var blob = new Blob([arrayBuffer], { type: photo.type });

       var pictureData = new FormData();
       pictureData.append('access_token:', this.state.FBaccessToken);
       pictureData.append('source', blob);

       return pictureData;
   }.bind(this)
   return reader.readAsArrayBuffer(photo);
   ```
3. Do a post request

   ```
   var encodedRequest = this.encodePhoto(photo);

   FB.api(
       "/me/photos?published=false",  
       "POST",
       encodedRequest,
       function (response) {
         if (response && !response.error) {
           //once successfully gotten the photos add them to the array of photo ids
           temp.push({"media_fbid": response.id});
           console.log(response);
         }
         else {
           alert(response.error.message);
         }
       }.bind(this)
   );
   ```

The error when I run it this way is that it doesn't seem to recognize the access token, but when I remove the access token from pictureData in step 2, and change the api encodedRequest part to this:

```
{
    access_token: this.state.FBaccessToken,
    source: encodedRequest,
},
```

I get the error *"(#324) Requires upload file"*. I tried adding `fileUpload: true,` to the SDK init code but that also didn't seem to do anything. Posting simple text only statuses and reading from feed is all working fine.

Sorry for the long post, but I'd be really grateful if anyone has any insight! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is it the extra colon you have after access_token in your first pictureData.append() call?

pictureData.append('access_token:', this.state.FBaccessToken); 
versus
pictureData.append('access_token', this.state.FBaccessToken);

Edit: Below is output from postman to post images referencing a file on my laptop

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("source", "/Users/patricklambe/images/test.jpg");
form.append("access_token", "PAGEACCESSTOKEN");
form.append("caption", "check this photo");

var settings = {
"async": true,
"crossDomain": true,
"url": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/444873272561515/photos",
"method": "POST",
"headers": {
"cache-control": "no-cache",
"postman-token": "1d786fec-c9b1-2494-1b5c-8fd0e2ea5ade"
},
"processData": false,
"contentType": false,
"mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
"data": form
  }

 $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

Comment: Nice catch, but unfortunately fixing that still results in it not recognizing the access token.

Comment: If you console log the token and debug it at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken does it provide anything helpful, or it says the token is valid? Do you have the specific message you receive when you say FB does not recognise the access token? Is it that the access token is missing, or a FB specific message about the token? Other thing I would suggest is appending the token to your _/me/photos?published=false_ url and see if the post works, then we'll know its the appending of the token to the form that is causing the issue.

Comment: It says that it's valid and when I added it to the end of the /me/photos url the error wasn't about the access token anymore, but changed to '(#324) Requires upload file'

Comment: I see. If you change your source to either a publically available URL, or the path to the image file on your machine, rather than a blob, does that work? I haven't seen much documentation supporting blob uploads for Facebook API.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, got sidetracked with other aspects of this project. I didn't see any mention of blob in the official documentation (or really any example of how to do this) but I saw a few people online saying they had success using a blob with formData.

I don't think I can use the local path of the file, from what I read I think for security reasons you don't get the actual path from input file.

Comment: No worries. I just ran it through Postman there using a file on my laptop and it seemed to post fine to FB. Outputting the code to Javascript, added what comes out to the original post, might it may be of some help, sorry it mightn't be exactly what you're looking for, hopefully someone else can provide help if the above doesn't suffice.